# Continuity and Leximin

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Consider a relation $\geq$ over the set of real-valued vectors. We say that $\geq$ is continuous if for any positive integer $n$, and any $\pi\in\mathbb Z^n,u\in\mathbb R ^n$ we have that the sets $\{v\in\mathbb R ^n:(\pi,v)\geq(\pi,u)\}$ and $\{v\in\mathbb R ^n:(\pi,v)\leq(\pi,u)\}$ are closed, where $(\pi,v)$ indicates the vector formed by appending $v$ to $\pi$.

(This is kind of a weird definition, but I think it's implied by [but isn't identical to?] [this one](http://planetmath.org/continuousrelation).)

The Leximin ordering is one where $x\geq y$ if the smallest value of $x$ is greater than the smallest value of $y$. If the smallest values are equal, we compare the second smallest, etc.

[Blackorby, Bossert and Donaldson](http://www.repugnant-conclusion.com/population-ethics.pdf) claim that the leximin ordering is not continuous. I'm struggling to understand why.

For example, consider $S=\{v:v\geq (0,0)\}$. This is the set $\{x:x_i\geq 0\}$. That set seems closed to me. For example, there doesn't seem to be anything less than $(0,0)$ itself.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, by $U[\pi,u]$ I will denote the set $$\{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n : ( \pi , u ) \leq ( \pi , v ) \}.$$

Fixing $\pi = \langle 0,0, \ldots , 0 \rangle \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, and let $u = \langle 1 , 3 , \ldots , 3 \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^n$, note that  for each $j > 0$ the $n$-tuple $v_j = \langle 1 + \frac{1}{j} ,  2, 2, \ldots , 2 \rangle$ belongs to the set $U[\pi,u]$.  Also note that the $v_j$ converge to $v = \langle 1 ,2,2, \ldots , 2 \rangle$, but $v \notin U_\leq[\pi,u]$.  It follows that $U[\pi,u]$ is not closed. (Note that I have implicitly assumed that $n > 1$; for $n=1$ the sets will be closed.)

(If you disallow tuples with equal entries, this example can be easily modified so that each tuple which appears has distinct entries.)